# What is this northern California perennial with variegated leaves with dark red lines on them?

Tags: identification, perennials

This is a perennial, growing in moist, shady conditions in northern California. Does anyone know what it is?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The plant pictured is [*Persicaria virginiana* 'Painter's Palette'](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=z320). The mottled green and white variegation, the leaf shape, and especially, the reddish chevrons make the identification unmistakable. The alternate leaves and stem appearance reinforce the id.

The plant will grow in full sun if it is provided adequate water, but is happier in part-shade. It is extremely hardy, growing from USDA zone 4 (probably zone 3 too) to zone 10. Typical height is 18-24" and spreading, making an effective ground cover. It sends up attractive red flowers on slender stems in the summer.

It could be invasive in some locations. The green form of [*Persicaria virginiana*](http://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=povi2) is native to eastern North America from Quebec to Florida.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had this plant years ago, I am sure of it...this has been bugging me.

Is this guy alternate leaved, woody, how big is it, is it in sun or shade and have you gotten any flowers or buds? How long are those leaves?

This really is bugging me.  I think it is a Polygonum, a Knot-weed.  Most are very invasive and a few have climbed to the tops of weeds-to-eradicate list.  Let me know 1) how high the plant is generally growing; 2) the general size of the leaves; 3) what the flowers look like...I am guessing Polygonum cuspidatum 'compactum'...a compact-growing Japanese Knot-weed.

The jointed stems with the base of the leaf wrapping around the stem is characteristic of Polygonums (sometimes listed as Persicaria).  The flowers should be spikes of pink to red.

Comment: How interesting that Persicaria is also part of the Polygonum family of knotweeds...dunno who has been down voting my answer but you should know I was correct.  Even with little information!!  Neennerneenerneener...gees!!  Major grins!!